# Urllib2 using tor in python

Tags: python, tor

I'm trying to crawl websites using a crawler written in Python, and want to integrate Tor with Python meaning I want to crawl the site anonymously using Tor.

I have found some answers on stackoverflow, but none of they work for me.

---

Here is the first solution I found from [Urllib2 using Tor and socks in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957470/urllib2-using-tor-and-socks-in-python)

```
import socks
import socket
import urllib2    
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
print urllib2.urlopen('http://my-ip.herokuapp.com').read()
```

but I get below error

```
(501, 'Tor is not an HTTP Proxy')
```

---

then, the accepted answer from [How can I use a SOCKS 4/5 proxy with urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317849/how-can-i-use-a-socks-4-5-proxy-with-urllib2)

```
import socks
import socket
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 8080)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
import urllib2
print urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
```

I get below error

```
<urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

---

then, the top voted answer from [Python urllib over TOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148589/python-urllib-over-tor)

```
import socks
import socket
def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

# patch the socket module
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

import urllib2
```

My test url is "http://almien.co.uk/m/tools/net/ip/", above code will run for 2 minutes, and end with below error

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 369, in connect
    self.__negotiatesocks5(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socks.py", line 236, in __negotiatesocks5
    raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

someone commented that the latest port is **9150** but **9050**, so I tried with **9150** again, and get below error

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

### UPDATE

Add tor information on my machine.

```
root@xxxxxxx:~# tor
Apr 22 14:14:39.818 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Apr 22 14:14:39.818 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 22 14:14:39.818 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 22 14:14:39.820 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 22 14:14:39.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Apr 22 14:14:39.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Apr 22 14:14:39.000 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
Apr 22 14:14:39.000 [warn] OpenSSL version from headers does not match the version we're running with. If you get weird crashes, that might be why. (Compiled with 1000105f: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013; running with 1000106f: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014).
Apr 22 14:14:40.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
```

Comment: Do you have tor running on your system?

Comment: Ah... how to check/turn on it? my os is ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Start tor then:

```
import socket
import urllib

import socks  # SocksiPy module
import stem.process

SOCKS_PORT = 9050

# Set socks proxy and wrap the urllib module

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', SOCKS_PORT)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

# Perform DNS resolution through the socket

def getaddrinfo(*args):
  return [(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 6, '', (args[0], args[1]))]

socket.getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo

print urllib.urlopen('http://my-ip.herokuapp.com').read()
```

Based on the [to_russia_with_love](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html) code using stem. If you want to also start tor from python you should check out [stem](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stem/).

Comment: Ah... how to check/turn on it? my os is ubuntu.

Comment: Just simply run tor, if not installed use sudo apt-get install tor

Comment: I have tried stem. Every time I run the script mentioned in to_russia_with_love, it will show "Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.", and then "OSError: reached a 90 second timeout without success", is it my network issue?

Comment: Does tor start ok normally?

Comment: I have updated my question with tor information. If you want to know more than that, please let me know

Comment: I have tried your script on my machine, it failed with _raise Socks5Error(ord(resp[1]),_generalerrors[ord(resp[1])])
IndexError: tuple index out of range_

Comment: did you start tor successfully previously from bash? try `killall tor` and try starting again

Comment: No progress, it's still stuck at 5% with a warning about SSL (please check my latest question). do you know how to figure it out?

Comment: do you have multiple versions of openssl installed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, are you able to explain why you monkey patched the `getaddrinfo` method? It still works even when commented out hence wondering. Also if I may ask, where the `args` to the `getaddrinfo` function came from?